# Clang optimizes to "ror" instruction in function but not when function is inlined

Tags: clang, clang++

I found a strange bug in clang optimization. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned int rot2(unsigned int a, size_t k) {
    return (a >> k) | (a << (sizeof(unsigned int) * 8 - k));
}

int main() {
    unsigned int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    auto n = rot2(x, 5);
    std::cout << n;
}
```

And here is assembly generated for clang 8.0.0 and 9.0.0 with `-O3` option (from godbolt):

```
rot2(unsigned int, unsigned long):                              # @rot2(unsigned int, unsigned long)
        mov     rcx, rsi
        mov     eax, edi
        ror     eax, cl
        ret
main:                                   # @main
        push    rax
        lea     rsi, [rsp + 4]
        mov     edi, offset std::cin
        call    std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_extract<unsigned int>(unsigned int&)
        mov     esi, dword ptr [rsp + 4]
        mov     rax, rsi
        shr     rax, 5
        shl     esi, 27
        or      rsi, rax
        mov     edi, offset std::cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_insert<unsigned long>(unsigned long)
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rcx
        ret
```

As you see, `rot2` method is optimized correctly and a `ror` instruction is used. But to my surprise, this instruction is not used in `main()` and the whole code is using shift and or instruction.

Any idea why this strange bug happens? gcc and msvc do not make this strange mistake.

Comment: It's not a 'bug' as such, in that it produces correct code; but appears to want to restore `%rcx` for some reason. (BTW - your test code really should have `return (0);` at the end of `main` - although it doesn't appear to make a difference in this case) The only thing I can think of is that **clang** doesn't have a full description of the possible `ror` encodings. Still not sure why `pop %rcx` is needed, unless it has something to do with global destructor code.

Comment: @BrettHale standard states `The body of the main function does not need to contain the return statement.` For c++. it will be equal to `return 0;`.